# npm install specific version does not install specific version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, react-router

My package.json says I have `react-router: 0.13.4` installed. However, when I type in the command `npm view react-router` it stats that it is using `version: '1.0.0-rc3`

I even tried `npm install react-router@0.13.4` but `npm view react-router` still produces version `1.0.0-rc3`

Answer (score 2):

I believe `npm view` shows details of the latest remote package release, not the installed version. Look at `node_modules/react-router/package.json` to see your installed version. Use the `npm install react-router@0.13.4 --save` command if you want to update your package.json file.

Answer (score 2):

npm install react-router-dom@5.3.0

then check the version in terminal with `npm view react-router-dom@5.3.0 version`
it will show the version of react router.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the `react-router` versioning on their [GitHub releases page](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/releases?after=v1.0.0-beta1), you will notice there is no version `0.13.4` after version `0.13.3`, which might be why NPM defaults to installing the latest version `1.0.0-rc3`.

Comment: you are correct. but when I `npm install react-router` this is the output: http://dpaste.com/2S4X0GR

Comment: Sorry, I might be wrong about version 0.13.4 not existing. I've just taken a look at their GitHub repo and they actually do have a version 0.13.4. Try running `npm install react-router@"^0.13.4"` to try to force NPM to install a version that starts with `0.13.4`.